# What does PINNED mean in -hc profile of Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, memory, profiling

I am trying to profile my application. When analyzing memory usage with `-hc` RTS option, I noticed lots of memory marked as PINNED. When running with `-hy` the memory is marked as `ARR_WORDS`.

The program creates a 2400×2400 matrix of doubles using `Data.Packed.Matrix` module from hmatrix package, and since the elements in it should be stored in continuous memory, I don't see a way for the matrix to take up so much space.

[image]

My question is: what does the PINNED word actually mean? Also is there a way to get further information on why and where the memory is used?

The whole source code in question is [on GitHub](https://github.com/lubomir/machacek), should anyone be interested in it. However, it is very far from minimal example.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/Pinned

Comment: In practice this probably means `ByteString` which is implemented with pinned `ByteArray#`

Answer (score 10):

"Pinned" data means that the garbage collector is not allowed to move it.  This helps, for example, when passing data to C functions via the FFI.  You wouldn't want the GC to move the data whilst the C call is executing.

Soylet Green gave the relevant link above (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/Pinned).